# Is it possible to execute a JavaScript function loaded in a WebBrowser control at any moment in AutoHotkey?

Tags: webbrowser-control, autohotkey

I thought [`InvokeScript`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/60924/Using-WebBrowser-Document-InvokeScript-to-mess-aro) may work but it didn't.

```
strHTML =
(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script> function displayDate() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date(); }</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo" onclick="displayDate()">This is a paragraph. Click here.</p>
    </body>
</html> 
)

new WebBrowser(strHTML)

Class WebBrowser
{
    __New(strHTML) { 
        static WB
        Gui, New, Resize 
        Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w780 h580 , Shell.Explorer  
        Gui, show, w800 h600

        WB.Navigate("about:blank")
        Loop
           Sleep 10
        Until (WB.readyState=4 && WB.document.readyState="complete" && !WB.busy)    

        WB.Document.Write(strHtml)
        ; WB.Document.Close()

        WB.document.InvokeScript("displayDate")
        ; WB.document.parentWindow.document.InvokeScript("displayDate") ; does not work
        return this

        GuiClose:
        ExitApp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways that you can call the function:

```
WB.document.parentWindow.execScript("displayDate()")
WB.document.parentWindow.displayDate()
```

All global functions within the script are available as methods of the `window` object.

The WebBrowser control referred in the article you linked to is part of the .NET Framework, and is not the same as the WebBrowser control you are using. This is why attempting to call `InvokeScript` raises an "Unknown name" error message.